# Mysqli not showing errors properly

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to learn mysqli properly I get most of the functions. One thing left to do is to have proper error reporting across all my layers. I don't understand why the following snippet of code detects an error but won't get the error number nor the error code.

```
function get_PID_TID_by_PK($con,$ourId)
{
    $returned['errno'] ="";
    $returned['error'] ="";
    //mistake is over here!!!
    if(!$stmt = $con->prepare("ELECT gene_name,jgi_protein_id,jgi_transcript_id FROM jgi_transid_protid_match where our_protein_id = ?"))
    {
        $returned['errno'] = $con->errno;
        $returned['error'] = $con->error;
        return $returned;
    }

    if(!$stmt->bind_param('s',$ourId))
    {
        $returned['errno'] = $stmt->errno;
        $returned['error'] = $stmt->error;

        return $returned;
    }

    if(!$stmt->execute())
    {
        $returned['errno'] = $stmt->errno;
        $returned['error'] = $stmt->error;

        return $returned;
    }

    $stmt->bind_result($gene_name,$jgi_protein_id,$jgi_transcript_id);
    $stmt->fetch();

    $fetchedArray['gene_name'] = $gene_name;
    $fetchedArray['jgi_protein_id'] = $jgi_protein_id;
    $fetchedArray['jgi_transcript_id'] = $jgi_transcript_id;

    //Have to use this hack since query returns an object and not an array and I don't want to make everything object oriented if you don't know what I am talking about just ignore this comment
    $returned['assoc'] = $fetchedArray;

    return $returned;
}
```

The mistake is obvious and on the 6th line I wrote ELECT instead of SELECT the program is getting inside that block but the errno and error are null. What am I doing wrong.This code works perfectly fine if I don't break it on purpose.

Comment: Have you looked for errors on `$stmt` at that point, too?

Comment: $stmt will return FALSE if there's an error I believe...

Comment: Yea according to the documentation the error won't be there if there is an error $stmt will be false.

Comment: May I ask what you gonna do with these errno and error?

Comment: I am using a layered architecture (MVC) these errors will be passed up all the way to the view then displayed there. I will most likely put a flag somewhere to turn this feature on or off.

Comment: To the view?! what these errors have to do with the view? Are you sure that site users interested in seeing them?

Comment: These errors have to be converted into PHP errors. And thus have to be handled according to server role - displayed (not by means of view) in a development mode, or *logged* on a live site. But again - they don't need no special treatment but handled along with other PHP errors

Comment: I never thought of it in that way. I should rethink a few things.

Comment: But I need to tell the user something went wrong instead of displaying a blank screen.

Comment: Sure. That's what [custom error handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) exactly for. It will catch any error and will show appropriate page to the user. And it will do that for any PHP error, with no additional code written

Comment: Hm this is exactly what I am looking for and very interesting. In lamens terms my mind is blown. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to go with using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php . I will redesign my code a bit and let the php error handler take care of all the errors and I will make a custom one for my database errors that are happening.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the IF statement is correct?

```
if(!$stmt = $con->prepare("ELECT gene_name,jgi_protein_id,jgi_transcript_id FROM jgi_transid_protid_match where our_protein_id = ?"))
{
    $returned['errno'] = $con->errno;
    $returned['error'] = $con->error;
    return $returned;
}
```

Should be

```
if(($stmt = $con->prepare("ELECT gene_name,jgi_protein_id,jgi_transcript_id FROM jgi_transid_protid_match where our_protein_id = ?")) === FALSE)
{
    $returned['errno'] = $con->errno;
    $returned['error'] = $con->error;
    return $returned;
}
```

Or split the assignment

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("ELECT gene_name,jgi_protein_id,jgi_transcript_id FROM jgi_transid_protid_match where our_protein_id = ?");
if($stmt === FALSE)
{
    $returned['errno'] = $con->errno;
    $returned['error'] = $con->error;
    return $returned;
}
```

Comment: Yea I was doing it the not so safe way but the results are the same in this case. I am still getting no errors.

Comment: Ive never tried to answer a question to create errors! First for me hehe!

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to learn mysqli properly

That's the only mistake you made.

With [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) your code would be... **three** lines long. And it will report all the errors properly

```
function get_PID_TID_by_PK($con,$ourId)
{
    $stmt = $con->prepare("ELECT gene_name,jgi_protein_id,jgi_transcript_id FROM jgi_transid_protid_match where our_protein_id = ?");
    $stmt->execute(array($ourId));
    return $stmt->fetch();
}
```

Comment: Interesting I might take a look at this.